# Rails - How to find errors in a huge production.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app used to log everything by default. Fixed this and now it's only logging errors, but how can I find the errors in the old log file. It's 42GB in size and I can't scroll through it.

My best guess so far:

```
tail -n 10000 production.log
```

But it gets cumbersome after a while.

Comment: linux 'grep' utility might help

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script to read it and parse it for the errors you are looking for, but that too is tedious.

I would strongly suggest implementing an error exception handling service.  There are opensource options as well as SaaS services that are well worth the money.

See https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification for a decent list of options.

I've used Honeybadger myself and loved it. I've also heard great things about rollbar.